# Convert User Input into a List name

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is what I have so far:

```
TotalLists=int(input("How many Lists are you making?"))
TotalListsBackup=TotalLists
Lists=[]

while TotalLists>0:
  ListName=input("What would you like to call List Number "+str(TotalLists))
  Lists.append(ListName)
  TotalLists=TotalLists-1

TotalLists=TotalListsBackup-1

while TotalLists>=0:
  Lists[TotalLists] #I would like to create actual lists out of the list names at this step but I dont know how...
  TotalLists=TotalLists-1

TotalLists=TotalListsBackup-1

print("Here are your Lists: ")

while TotalLists>=0:
  print(Lists[TotalLists])
  TotalLists=TotalLists-1
```

I want to be able to:

- create a List out of the List Names
- The code to be able to make as many lists as the user wants to without a cap

For example, I want to input: Grocery,
The code will create a list Called Grocery

---

Solutions I have thought of:

- Arrays? (I have never used them, I am very new to Python Programming and I dont know too much)
- Lists of Lists? (Not sure how to do that. Looked it up, but didn't get a straight answer)
- Using Variables, Creating a list with a name like:

  ```
  List1[]
  ```

and have varible called:

```
    List1Name=input("What would you like to call list 1?")
```

I do not know how to create an infinite number of lists using this way though.

If you have any questions please ask, for I know I am not good at explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting that you have tagged the question "dictionary" but didn't mention that in your post.  Did somebody tell you to use a dictionary?  That's exactly what you should be doing, like this (assume TotalLists is already defined):

```
d = {}

for _ in range(TotalLists):   # The same loop you have now
    ListName = input("whatever...")
    d[ListName] = []
```

At the end of this you have a dictionary d containing keys that are the user-entered names, and values that are empty lists.  The number of dictionary entries is TotalLists.  I'm ignoring the possibility that the user will enter the same name twice.

Comment: Perfect! Just One Question Though, is there a way I can have another key along with the User-entered one. That way I can print them all out in a nicer way with a for loop, for example:---

 for name in Index:
    print(name)
    for item in Index[]:
        print(item) --- But that doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what this other key would be.  You can have a second dictionary, of course, to associate user-entered names with some other object of your choice.  Also you can sort the list of keys (use the built-in `sorted` function) and loop through it to make a nicely formatted, alphabetized printout.

Answer (score 0):

You're solving an XY problem. There's no need to ask for the number of `list`s in advance. I would recommend using a dictionary:

```
>>> lists = {}
>>> while 1:
...     newlist = input("Name of new list (leave blank to stop)? ")
...     if newlist:
...             lists[newlist] = []
...             while 1:
...                     newitem = input("Next item? ")
...                     if newitem:
...                             lists[newlist].append(newitem)
...                     else:
...                             break
...     else:
...             break
...
Name of new list (leave blank to stop)? groceries
Next item? apples
Next item? bananas
Next item?
Name of new list (leave blank to stop)? books
Next item? the bible
Next item? harry potter
Next item?
Name of new list (leave blank to stop)?
>>> lists
{'groceries': ['apples', 'bananas'], 'books': ['the bible', 'harry potter']}
```