# Assign user input as name for a list in python

Tags: list

This question may be a duplicate of "[Convert User Input into a List Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338452/convert-user-input-into-a-list-name)". But what I am trying figure out is why  does the last line of code not print the user's entry?

```
MyList = {}
UserListName = raw_input("Insert List Name")
MyList[UserListName]=[]
print "The user list name is ", MyList[UserListName]
```

It ends up printing "The user list name is []" though I am expecting "The user list name is JohnsList". If it read

```
print "The user list name is ", UserListName
```

wouldn't that just read the input only and not display it in list form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that the last line should read as follows to include user entry

```
print "The user list name is ", MyList
```